# Upload Image to .NET Server with C#

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm semi new to .NET and after doing quite a few tests - I decided to come ask here. I'm trying to allow users to upload a photo, and then save the photo to a specific path. I've found a lot of stuff on MSDN that involves using an `<asp:~>` tag with variables inside of it - But I always get an error saying "asp.net attributes are only allowed in asp.net files" - I'm working on this project for a friend trying to give him some functionality I have in my node project.

A bare-basic Codepen of the effect I'm trying to get is 
[here @ Codepen](http://codepen.io/dnorthrupva/pen/xVwmaM)

I'm aware that Codepen would lack the ability to 'save' due to security - So I'm trying to find a C# alternative. The code I'm finally with, that is close to my end result is:

In the Controller

```
@{  
    WebImage photo = null;
    var newFileName = "";
    var imagePath = "";

    if(IsPost){
        photo = WebImage.GetImageFromRequest();
        if(photo != null){
            newFileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "_" +
                Path.GetFileName(photo.FileName);
        imagePath = @"images\" + newFileName;

        photo.Save(@"~\" + imagePath);
        }
    }
}
```

And in the view

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <fieldset>
        <legend> Upload Image </legend>
        <label for="Image">Image</label>
        <input type="file" name="Image" />
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
<h1>Uploaded Image</h1>
@if(imagePath != ""){
    <div class="result">
        <img src="@imagePath" alt="image" />
    </div>
}
```

Please note in the view I deleted the "@if" section all the way to it's closing - It doesn't seem to render correctly in the cshtml. [I'm assuming cshtml and ASP.NET aren't quite the same.]

If anyone could provide guidance, I would appreciate it.

Functionality would just be - User hits 'Upload'. Choose files. I save the file with a name I assign (Will be a variable based on information provided prior).

This issue could also lie within my placement of the 'controller'. I assumed it went into the controller that handled the function of this page.

What's currently happening with the code is the image is selectable, and it accepts it - When I hit Upload, it just refreshes the page and nothing happens. If the file is going somewhere, I don't know where.

Thanks!

Comment: Views with the .cshtml or .vbhtml extension use [Razor syntax](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-razor-syntax-c), whereas pages that end in .aspx or .asax use WebForms -  both are part of ASP.NET.

Comment: Thanks Tieson! I'll re-direct my searches to Razor specifics then. I wasn't sure of the difference. They're all cshtml.

Comment: What project template are you using? Controllers are usually C# classes, not view pages (so there should not be any Razor markup there), assuming you're using Visual Studio and it's project templates.

Comment: It's actually someone's MVC - I believe they used MVC 3.
The view is another file inside of the View. The "Controller" code I put it inside of the controller it references.

Sorry if I'm using wrong terminology.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry, but I'm not entirely following you. There's a routing engine, which takes the current URL and parses it to figure out which controller class needs to handle the request, and then which action (a method of the controller class) being executed on the controller. The action returns a result of some sort, most often a call to the View() method, which renders the Razor/WebForms (and HTML) markup found in the appropriate view.

Comment: If you don't have controller classes, I suspect you're working on a Web Pages project, which is a little different.

Comment: yeah seems like its not clear what tech your using... and then your mixing them... please include all code. i.e. how did your form know which controller to hit. please include the controller name and action. Please show code for GetImageFromRequest. Its wield cozs it feel like your almost there but at the same time... quite lost. Its unclear without showing more to where you stand ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the Question, but if you are trying to save a image in c# this should help you
[Problem saving an uploaded image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323608/problem-saving-an-uploaded-image)

and be careful with the permission that Windows operating enforces